# How to capture mouse input for PolymerElement

Tags: dart, polymer

I am developing a Polymer-based Web Component in Dart and can't find a way to capture mouse input (so that the element keeps receiving MouseMove events even after the mouse pointer left control's bounds). This is required for implementing drag-like functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the component can listen to document.onMouseXxx. It is not limited to it's component. If you don't want to register to document events generally you can start listening when you recognize a dragStart 'inside' the component and stop listening to global events after dropping.

I did a bit of Drag 'n Drop in BWU Datagrid. The column reordering is done with just mouseDown, mouseMove, mouseEnter, mouseLeave, mouseUp events the row reordering example uses dragStart, dragOver, dragEnter, dragLeave, and drop events.

http://bwu-dart.github.io/bwu_datagrid/example/e09_row_reordering.html

Comment: I am listening to the canvas.onMouseMove event, and it is not being fired when the mouse moves outside of canvas. But I see that your example works, so I will be taking a closer look at it. Thanks!

Comment: When you want get notified about mouseMove events outside of the element you need to register on the page. `document.onMouseMove.listen`